# How Sound of Mobile Vibration travels through wire of Earphones

Tags: everyday-life, vibrations

This may sound dumb, but I have been observing that, If my mobile phone is placed on the wire of my hands free (earphones) and if my mobile vibrates, I could listen the vibration from the ear plugs. I first thought that it is just my imagination, but every time my mobile is placed on my earphones wire i could totally listen the mobile vibrating through the earplugs, even when I am listening to loud music, I could still totally hear the vibration clearly.

What is the phenomenon behind this ?

Comment: Maybe this will explain it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_can_telephone

Answer (score 1):

The little motors for making electronics vibrate are electrically noisy, and the signal can leak into the audio system.